# Class attributes and their initialization

Tags: python, class, attributes

I'm quite new in python and during these days I'm exploring classes. I have a question concerning attributes and variables inside classes: What is the difference between defining an attribute via just `q=1` in the body of the class and via defining `self.q=1` inside the `__init__`? For example, what is the difference between the following two possibilities?

```
class MyClass1:
    q=1
    def __init__(self,p):
        self.p=p
    def AddSomething(self,x):
        self.q = self.q+x
```

and

```
class MyClass2:
    def __init__(self,p):
        self.q=1
        self.p=p
    def AddSomething(self,x):
        self.q = self.q+x
```

The output of for example:

```
>>> my=MyClass1(2)
>>> my.p
2
>>> my.q
1
>>> my.AddSomething(7)
>>> my.q
8
```

does not depend on whether `MyClass1` or `MyClass2` is used. Neither in `MyClass1` nor in `MyClass2` does an error occur.

Comment: Hint: what does `MyClass.q` and `MyClass.p` give in either case?

Comment: And another hint: what if `q` was a list, and `AddSomething` appended to it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Classes as well as their instances in python uses dictionary like data structure to store the information.

So for each class definition, a dictionary will be allocated where the class level information (class variables) will be stored. And for each instance of that particular class, a separate dictionary(self) will be allocated where the instance specific information(instance variables) will be stored.

So now the next question is:
**How the lookup for a particular name will be performed ??**

And answer to this question is that if you are accessing the names through some instance, the instance specific dictionary will be searched first and if the name is not found there, then the class dictionary will be searched for that name. So if the same value is defined at both levels that former one will be overridden.

*Note that when you write d['key'] = val where d is a dictionary, 'key' will automatically be added to the dictionary if not already present. Otherwise the current value will be overwritten. Keep this in mind before reading the further explanation.*

Now lets go through the code you have used to describe your problem:

**MyClass1**

```
class MyClass1:
    q=1
    def __init__(self,p):
        self.p=p
    def AddSomething(self,x):
        self.q = self.q+x
```

---

```
1. my = Myclass1(2) #create new instance and add variables to it.

    MyClass = {"q" : 1}
    my = {"p" : 2}
```

---

```
2. my.p    # =2, p will be taken from Dictionary of my-instance.
```

---

```
3. my.q    # =1, q will be takn from MyClass dict. (Not present in dictionary of my-instance).
```

---

```
4. my.AddSomething(7) # This method access the value of q (using self.q) first 
                      # which is not defined in my dict and hence will be taken
                      # from dictionary of MyClass. After the addition operation,
                      # the sum is being stored in self.q. Note that now we are
                      # adding the name q to Dictionary of my-instance and hence                   
                      # a new memory space will be created in Dictionary of my-instance
                      # and the future references to self.q will fetch the value
                      # of self.q from dictionary of my-instance.

    MyClass = {"q" : 1}
    my = {"p" : 2, "q" : 8}
```

---

```
5. my.q   # =8, q now is available in dictionary of my-instance.
```

Answer (score 4):

`q=1` inside the class is a class attribute, associated with the class as a whole and not any particular instance of the class. It is most clearly accessed using the class itself: `MyClass1.q`.

A instance attribute is assigned directly to an instance of a class, usually in `__init__` by assigning to `self` (such as with `self.p = p`), but you can assign attributes to an instance at any time.

Class attributes can be *read* either using the class binding (`MyClass.q`) or an instance binding (`my.q`, assuming it is not shadowed by an instance attribute with the same name). They can only be *set*, however, using a class binding. Setting a value with an instance binding *always* modifies an instance attribute, creating it if necessary. Consider this example:

```
>>> a = MyClass1()
>>> a.q
1
>>> a.q = 3    # Create an instance attribute that shadows the class attribute
3
>>> MyClass1.q
1
>>> b = MyClass1()
>>> b.q   # b doesn't have an instance attribute q, so access the class's
1
```

Comment: So, to say it in other words (but correct me, if I'm wrong): In case MyClass2, `q` can neither be accessed from external via `MyClass2.q` nor can it be changed. In case MyClass1, `q` can be accessed from external via `MyClass1.q`. Changing it from external via `MyClass1.q=77` is possible and would affect all subsequently created instances.

Comment: Well, in the code you posted, `MyClass2.q` simply doesn't exist yet. You can create if after defining `MyClass2` with something like `MyClass2.q = <some value>`. But otherwise, I think you've got it.

Answer (score 2):

The most significant difference between the `q` attribute in this classes is that in `MyClass1` implementation the variable will be shared across all the instances of this class, while in `MyClass2` it's only visible in the scope of this particular object.

Some docs: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables