# Do the attributes inside the init method have to be class or instance attributes or both?

Tags: python

I would like to answer about the body of the init method (the attributes). Are the attributes inside the init method class or instance?. To be clearer, Can both class and instance attributes be defined within the body of the init constructor? Thanks a lot.

Comment: We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour]. Could you give some context for the question? I could write an answer, but I'd like to understand why you're asking the question. For example, if it's about a problem with code that you're writing, then I'd recommend providing your code so we can propose a solution. See [ask] for tips.

Comment: @CFreitas:  I'm sort of curious myself.  Can both class and instance attributes be defined within the body of the init constructor?

Comment: And if so, how?  Doesn't seem like a difficult question to answer.

Comment: I'm also confused why you think something can be a class *and* instance attribute. That's not really possible, but maybe it depends on the terminology you're using, or maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30258788

Comment: @wjandrea what I mean is that exist class attributes and instance attributes

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can define both inside init. However for clarity and for clearing keeping them in different places, we generally keep them above the `__init__` constructor.

To Python interpreter, it is just another value. If you can access it, you can use it.

Just keep in mind that for modifying class variables, you will need to use class methods if you want to avoid using the class name in code. The first arg for class method is generally called `cls` but it can be anything you like even `self` and it would operate over the class. You can call it using instance or class both.

Please see below.

I have a class

```
class Sample:
    class_variable = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = Sample.class_variable
        Sample.class_variable += 1
        Sample.class_name = 'SAMPLE CLASS'
        self.instance_variable = self.id
        print(f'New Value of class variable is: {Sample.class_variable}')
        print(f'Value of class name is: {Sample.class_name}')

    def change_instance_variable(self, new_value):
        self.instance_variable = new_value
        print(f'New Value of instance variable is: {self.instance_variable}')

    def change_class_variable(self, new_value):
        self.class_variable = new_value # this will just create an instance variable with the name class_variable
        print(f'New Value of class variable is: {Sample.class_variable}')

    @classmethod
    def really_change_class_variable(cls, new_value):
        cls.class_variable = new_value
        print(f'New Value of class variable is: {Sample.class_variable}')

    @classmethod
    def really_change_class_name(cls, new_value):
        cls.class_name = new_value

    def define_a_instance_variable_class_name(self):
        self.class_name = 'this instance variable will shadow class variable if referred by instance'
```

I use it for running an example:

```
a = Sample()
b = Sample()
a.change_instance_variable(10)
b.change_instance_variable(20)
a.change_class_variable(50)
a.really_change_class_variable(50)
Sample.really_change_class_name('Another Name')
c = Sample()
Sample.really_change_class_name('Another Name')
print(Sample.class_name)
print(c.class_name)
c.define_a_instance_variable_class_name()
print(Sample.class_name)
print(c.class_name)
```

which gives me following output:

```
New Value of class variable is: 1
Value of class name is: SAMPLE CLASS
New Value of class variable is: 2
Value of class name is: SAMPLE CLASS
New Value of instance variable is: 10
New Value of instance variable is: 20
New Value of class variable is: 2
New Value of class variable is: 50
New Value of class variable is: 51
Value of class name is: SAMPLE CLASS
Another Name
Another Name
Another Name
this instance variable will shadow class variable if referred by instance
```